# Variable inside Array

Tags: php

Why does this not work:

```
$emails = $_POST["emails"];
$emails = "'" . implode("','", explode(' ', $emails)) . "' ";
// The result is emails like this: 'foo@bar.com','foo@bar.com'

$to = array($emails);
```

How do i get the variable `$emails` into my array? (Learning PHP as I am sure is evident)

Comment: you need to add some more details, its not clear what you wish to achieve.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish here. If you just  wanted the emails in an array then `explode(' ', $emails)` already accomplishes just that. (Assuming they are space-delimited)

Comment: @Dagon Sorry I didn't provide enough info - I thought it was just a syntax error

Comment: *Lack of knowledge* error :) hah thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So it sounds like $_POST['emails'] is a space separated list that you want to get into an array?

Just do this:

```
$email_array = explode(' ', $_POST['emails']);
```

Of course you probably want to do some input validation before getting to this point.

Comment: This is it - sorry for not providing enough info I thought it was just a syntax error. +1 and will accept when I can

Answer (score 1):

You're setting `$to` to an array with one index who's value is a string `'foo@bar.com','foo@bar.com'`

If you want an array of emails, take off the `implode`

```
$emails = explode(' ', $emails); // an array
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish with your code here, but you're going from string, to array, to string, to array.

Answer (score 1):

The PHP function `explode` will return an array of the values separated.

If the emails are already separated by spaces in `$_POST['emails']` then you don't need to implode.

This will help:

```
$emails = $_POST["emails"];
$to = explode(' ', $emails);
```